# Bootstrap Nested Row Column Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way that I can make the nested columns height equal the row height? Currently they only equal 75% of the row height. I have tried setting the column height vs css, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Current Visitors</h1>
                    <h2>0</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h1>Online Orders</h1>
                  <h2>00</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                Grid Here
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0cL2qaq1/3/

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain what the css is doing in a little more detail?

Comment: @Deltatuk I honestly do not know the details on why it works, its a saved code snippet that I tend to use a lot, I just never looked into why it works... Sorry

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith what if I want to make col-4 shrink, adjust to col-8, make height rows inside col-4 become short